# Load a widget from a map or list

Tags: flutter

I have a very long list of report widgets that basically define a layout of data. I Want to be able to dynamically load those widgets from some other way that do conditional (if/else) or switches.

```
class ReportLibrary {
  final data;
  ReportLibrary(this.data);

  Map<String,Widget> _library = {
    'QuestionsAndScores': QuestionScoresView,
  };

  Widget get(String key){
    return _library[key](data);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or there is a better way.

Here is the errors:

```
flutter: Attempted to use type 'QuestionScoresView' as a function. Since types do not define a method 'call',
flutter: this is not possible. Did you intend to call the QuestionScoresView constructor and forget the 'new'
flutter: operator?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create string to subclass map - and then instantiate an instance of the subclass. This isn't allowed in Dart without mirrors, which you cannot use in Flutter.

Why wouldn't you use a `switch`? It's a little more verbose, but would work.

```
Widget get(String key) {
  case 'QuestionsAndScores':
    return QuestionScoresView(data);
  // etc
}
```

Equally, you could have a map of string to function:

```
  final _library = <String, Function>{
    'QuestionsAndScores': (data) => QuestionScoresView(data),
  };

  Widget foo = _library['QuestionsAndScores'](data);
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. Since this list is going to be about 40 long

Comment: But how is that different from a map with 40 entries?

Comment: Don't worry about performance. The compiler will create code that switches on the hash of the key string under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to make a call from `Map` value, that's what the error message says:

Change:

```
return _library[key](data);
```

to:

```
return _library[key];
```

This is how you access map value: `_library[key]`.

Update:

Make sure your `Map` value is `Widget` and add paranthesis`()` to `QuestionScoresView` otherwise you are assinging the `Type`. That will causes the error message that you commented(`The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the map value type 'Widget'`).

class

```
ReportLibrary {
    final data;
    Map<String, Widget> _library;
    ReportLibrary(this.data) { 
        _library = {
            'QuestionsAndScores': QuestionScoresView(),
        };
    }

  Widget get(String key){
    return _library[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get: error: The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the map value type 'Widget'. (map_value_type_not_assignable at [*] lib/ui/views/reports/report_library.dart:9)

Comment: @JasonSpick what is the type of `QuestionScoresView`. It have to be a type of widget or child of it

Comment: It is a StatelessWidget

Comment: @JasonSpick If it is a stateless widget you have to create a instance as value `QuestionScoresView()`. Otherwise Map try to get the value as `Type`. Let me know if this fix your problem.

Comment: QuestionScoresView requires data to be passed. I then get:Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Comment: Try it inside your constructor and you have to pass values to your params that is required for `QuestionScoresView`.

Comment: @JasonSpick We cannot store the class name in map and then use that stored class name to call the constructor

Comment: @JasonSpick Richard Heap answer is great. Use that approach.

Comment: @Blasanka its a long report list. Is using switch case good idea?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using for entering value to the map is wrong, it is used to refer a function in flutter and so your error message says so.

you should change this:

```
Map<String,Widget> _library = {
  'QuestionsAndScores': QuestionScoresView,
};
```

to something like this:

```
Map<String,Widget> _library = {
  'QuestionsAndScores': QuestionScoresView(),
};
```

I hope it helps, let me know if you have any doubts.